# Making a 'div' go in a circle

Tags: javascript, animation, rotation

I am working on a bit of code to have a dot circle around your cursor on a webpage, but I am having trouble getting the 'div' to follow the path I want; in fact, the object is not moving at all and I cannot figure out why my code does not work. Here is the code that is causing me trouble from what I've narrowed down:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<head>
<title>TEST SPACE</title>
<script src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="test"></div>
<style>
#test {
    background-color: black;
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
}
</style>
<script>
const omega = Math.PI / 2000;

function dotRotation() {
    var time = 0;

    var x = 20*(Math.sin(omega*time));
    var y = 20*(Math.cos(omega*time));

    document.getElementById("test").style.marginLeft = x;
    document.getElementById("test").style.marginTop = y;

    time += 25;
};

$(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval('dotRotation()',25);
});
</script>
</body>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ytnt2/2/)

Comment: I'd suggest doing the div rotation with CSS(3), not javaScript.

Comment: Check out ["Secret #6" on Lea Verou's presentation: *Deep CSS Secrets 10 things you may not know about CSS*](http://lea.verou.me/more-css-secrets/#secret6)

Comment: Memories from the 90's. Cursor trails and following eyeballs.

Comment: No where in the code do you get the cursor position.

Comment: @ZachL, the fiddle is set up wrong...that is the cause of the errors.

Comment: Also, since you have jQuery on the page, you really ought to leverage it rather than using the clunky vanilla JS. `document.getElementById("test").style.marginLeft = x +'px';` could be `$('#test').css('margin-left', x)

Answer (score 1):

Two things are wrong

1. You need to move your `time` variable outside of the function
2. You need to give a unit to the value you pass to the margins so add `+'px'` after the variables `.marginTop = y + 'px';`

So altogether

```
const omega = Math.PI / 2000;
var time = 0;

function dotRotation() {
    var x = 20*(Math.sin(omega*time));
    var y = 20*(Math.cos(omega*time));
    var style = document.getElementById("test").style;

    style.marginLeft = x +'px';
    style.marginTop = y +'px';

    time += 25;
};
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/mWC63/

---

Also you can cache references to the dom to avoid the searching

Comment: @ZachL, the string in the setInterval is not wrong.. just not recommended.. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setInterval and the `setInterval(code,delay)` syntax

Comment: Personally, I'd use this.time in the function (setting it when undefined), rather than suffer a global variable.

Comment: Actually, how about using `Date.now()`?

Comment: Oops, you're totally right. I even (mis) read that same DOC page before my initial post. Lol.

Answer (score 0):

Your fiddle is set to run onload, it should be set up to run in the head. [drop down on left under jQuery selection.]

`time` is declared inside of the function so it is reset back to zero every single time it is called. Move it outside of `dotRotation`

```
var time = 0;
function dotRotation() {

    var x = 20*(Math.sin(omega*time));
    var y = 20*(Math.cos(omega*time));

    $("#test").css({"marginLeft" : x + "px", "marginTop" : y + "px"});

   time += 25;
};
$(function() {
    setInterval(dotRotation,25);
});
```